# how to use pattern attribute allowing some strings as well

Tags: html, regex

I am using the pattern: `[s]{1}[1-9]{1,6}`

I am trying to match these conditions:

- It should start with `s`
- Followed by numeric characters (with maximum 6 digits)
- Blank not allowed

It's working fine at the moment, but how can I also allow a few specific values in this regex, e.g. "admin", "superAdmin"?

Answer (score 0):

```html
<input type="text" pattern="^(([s]{1}[1-9]{1,6})|admin|superAdmin)$" />
```

Comment: many thanks, its worked. Can I allow any case of admin, OR superAdmin?
e.g. Admin,admin,ADMIN,aDmIN
because if I add all this in pattern attribute, it will become too lengthy.

Comment: Unfortunately, html pattern attribute is always case-sensitive, you'll have to use this: ```<input type="text" pattern="^(([s]{1}[1-9]{1,6})|[aA][dD][mM][iI][nN]|[sS][uU][pP][eE][rR][aA][dD][mM][iI][nN])$" />```

Comment: its working fine for new users trying to login, but when I try to login with existing users , its giving UI validation errors e.g. s123456, s645321